# PowerShell delete SharePoint page section

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to remove a SharePoint page section using PowerShell. I'm following this example https://dreamsof.dev/2019-04-17-removing-sharepoint-page-sections/ which I remember used to work.

This is my first attempt:

```
$page = Get-PnPPage -Identity "Home.aspx"
$page.Sections.RemoveAt(0)
Set-PnPPage -Identity $page -Publish
```

That didn't work, so I want to check what is actually in the page section array before and after:

```
$page = Get-PnPPage -Identity "Home.aspx"
$beforeSections = $page.Sections
$page.Sections.RemoveAt(0)
Set-PnPPage -Identity $page -Publish
$page = Get-PnPPage -Identity "Home.aspx"
$afterSections = $page.Sections
```

But the variables `$beforeSections` and `$afterSections` contain both 2 sections

I'm sure this used to work. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my end and it does not work either. I have a check on the methods and it seems there is no remove method. Just like the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564130/powershell-delete-sharepoint-page-section) saying.
[image]

There is [Add-PnPPageSection](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/dev/documentation/Add-PnPPageSection.md) cmdlet but only [Remove-PnPPageComponent](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/dev/documentation/Remove-PnPPageComponent.md#remove-pnppagecomponent).